# IIS7 URL Rewrite Patterns Query Template after QueryString

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am creating a Friendly URL Patterns in IIS Rewrite

my normal URL would look like this

http://localhost/orgprofile/financial.aspx?name=Test

and initially I picked from the options available in IIS

the friendly URL with

http://localhost/orgprofile/financial/test

With Pattern

^orgprofile/financial/([^/]+)/?$

Now I only want to change the friendly URL to

http://localhost/test/financial

So yes the querystring first then append financial

I can get this friendly URL to work

http://localhost/financial/test

^financial/([^/]+)/?$

But cant get this to work

http://localhost/test/financial

i.e something like

([^/]+)/?$/^financial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ means the end of the query string - you need to leave that at the end.

Try:

```
^([^/]+)/financial/?$
```

Comment: Cool that worked and then for my outbound Rules I had to choose for my initial friendly URL of orgprofile/financial/microsoft which is ^(.*/)orgprofile/financial\.aspx\?name=([^=&]+)$ how can I edit for the url microsoft/financial....so again drop orgprofile, the qeuerystring value first then financial

Comment: Could you edit your original question and say what you're trying to translate to what - not sure what you need here.  If it helps this uses regular expression syntax: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: @schizodactyl can you post complete rule so it will b great help